# Call an aui:script function in JavaScript or convert aui:script code in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, liferay-aui

I need to call in JavaScript one of the two `aui:script` functions from the source code below, or to convert this `aui:script` source code in JavaScript code (in this way it would be easier for me).

```
<c:if test="<%= portletDisplay.isShowConfigurationIcon() %>">
    <aui:script use="aui-editable,aui-io-request">
        var i = A.one('#theId').get('value');
        for(var j=1;j<=i;j++) 
        { 
         addElement('<%=portletDisplay.getURLClose()%>','<%= themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages() %>','<%= color %>','<%= StringUtil.replace(HtmlUtil.escape(data), "&lt;br /&gt;", "<br />") %>');
        }   
        var quickNotePad = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />pad'+0);
        alert('#<portlet:namespace />pad'+0);


        if (quickNotePad) {
            quickNotePad.all('.note-color').on(
                'click',
                function(event) {
                    var box = event.currentTarget;

                    var bgColor = box.getStyle('backgroundColor');

                    quickNotePad.setStyle('backgroundColor', bgColor);

                    A.io.request(
                        '<%= themeDisplay.getPathMain() %>/quick_note/save',
                        {
                            data: {
                                color: bgColor,
                                p_auth: Liferay.authToken,
                                p_l_id: '<%= plid %>',
                                portletId: '<%= portletDisplay.getId() %>'
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }


        new A.Editable(
            {
                inputType: 'textarea',
                node: '#<portlet:namespace />note'+0,
                on: {
                    contentTextChange: function(event) {
                        var instance = this;

                        if (!event.initial) {
                            var newValue = event.newVal.replace(/\n/gi, '<br />');

                        alert('#<portlet:namespace />note'+0);

                            event.newVal = instance._toText(event.newVal);

                            A.io.request(
                                '<%= themeDisplay.getPathMain() %>/quick_note/save',
                                {
                                    data: {
                                        data: newValue,
                                        p_auth: '<%= AuthTokenUtil.getToken(request) %>',
                                        p_l_id: '<%= plid %>',
                                        portletId: '<%= portletDisplay.getId() %>'
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );

    </aui:script>
</c:if>
```

Could anyone give me an idea, please? I've already tried to do it in some ways, but it doesn't work... Thanks.